# Why I have warning in code in line 31

Tags: c++

Could you tell me what i should do ? I have warning in line 31
"extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]"
Why ? Where shoul i declare dzis TAB ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Zbior_znakow
{
    int indeks;
    static const int MaxEl = 255;
    int licznik;
public:

    char Tablica[MaxEl];

    void zbior_dodaj(unsigned char c);
    int zbior_nalezy(unsigned char c);
    int zbior_licznosc();
    Zbior_znakow();
    int zbior_rozne();
};

void Zbior_znakow::zbior_dodaj(unsigned char c)
{
    indeks = 0;
    Tablica[indeks]=c;
    indeks++;
}

Zbior_znakow::Zbior_znakow()
{
    for(int i=0 ;i<MaxEl;i++)
        Tablica [i]= {'0'};
}
```

Comment: Tell us where line 31 is?

Comment: It´s the last one (except for the braces)

Comment: I think you need `Tablica [i]= '0';`

Comment: It is a good practice to use english language only in source code, especially for class and variable names.

Comment: Thanks for help! Benio- next time I use only English in source code.

Answer (score 3):

Type of Tablica[i] is char not list so its assignment should be like this:

```
Tablica [i]= '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using initialization list syntax to add an element to an array of `char`, you can change this

```
for(int i=0 ;i<MaxEl;i++)
    Tablica [i]= {'0'};
```

To this

```
for(int i=0 ;i<MaxEl;i++)
    Tablica [i]= '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have it like that, since it apprears you only want to initialize the value to `0`

Try this:

```
for(int i=0 ;i<MaxEl;i++)
    Tablica [i]= '0'; //Don't need the { }
```